# Check whether a user removed the app from their respective account

Tags: facebook, oauth

In application I'm trying to add user verification by sms, email, facebook and google login. It makes user more reliable.

So how could I check if user removed the app from their own fb/google account ? I will move the verification Item to non-verified section according to it. Is there any tricky side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your App Settings and click on "Settings - Advanced". You will find the "Deauthorize Callback URL", it will get called whenever a user deauthorizes your Facebook App.

Comment: Additionally, have a look at the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#deauth-callback